# Why i got many replay log files on mac where no replication is running?

Tags: mysql

Mysql on mac is generating a lot of relay log files, but no replication is actually running. So why? How to delete them?

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS ;
Empty set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

ls data/
...
-rw-r-----    1 _mysql  _mysql       156 27 Jan 09:36 my-mac-relay-bin.000117
-rw-r-----    1 _mysql  _mysql       156 27 Jan 11:41 my-mac-relay-bin.000118
-rw-r-----    1 _mysql  _mysql       179 27 Jan 23:04 my-mac-relay-bin.000119
-rw-r-----    1 _mysql  _mysql       156 28 Jan 09:25 my-mac-relay-bin.000120
-rw-r-----    1 _mysql  _mysql       156 28 Jan 12:36 my-mac-relay-bin.000121
-rw-r-----    1 _mysql  _mysql       156 29 Jan 18:57 my-mac-relay-bin.000122
-rw-r-----    1 _mysql  _mysql       179 29 Jan 22:34 my-mac-relay-bin.000123
-rw-r-----    1 _mysql  _mysql       179 30 Jan 22:28 my-mac-relay-bin.000124
...
```

Comment: The dates on those files is from more than three weeks ago (we are writing this on 25 Feb). Was replication running at the time of those files' timestamps? And subsequently you did RESET SLAVE to clear the replication configuration?

Comment: No, the files are generating every day. And i never set up any replication since mysql installation. That's why i ask this question

Comment: Okay then try `RESET SLAVE` or if you use MySQL 8.0, use `RESET REPLICA` (same feature, different name). Read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reset-replica.html

Comment: thx, the reset slave seems to be working (all old files cleaned, but most recent one remaining). I'm still wondering why the server is creating relay logs in the first place.

Comment: I don't know, I've never seen relay logs appear this way. Is there another MySQL Server instance on this computer using the same directory for its relay logs?

Comment: No, ps shows only one such process. Never mind, so far good as long as i don't have to manually delete old relay files. Thx.